# Can I pass to route prefix non required arguments?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Laravel documentation has sample example how to craete route groups with prefix:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users', function () {
        // Matches The "/admin/users" URL
    });
});
```

Can I pass to prefix not required arguments, e.g:

```
Route::prefix('{lang?}')->group(function ($lang = "en") {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

Without lang argument URL will be: http://website.com/en

With lang argument URL will be: http://website.com/lang

It's correct or if incorrect how to correct it?

Comment: you need a prefix for localization, if yes, there is a [package](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) for that.

Comment: your code is working or not?